# Nesting oneOf in anyOf for a JSON Schema

Tags: jsonschema, ajv

Here is the JSON Schema and the JSON as provided below in the link for illustartion purpose.

[JSON Schema and the JSON](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdrALrESCeAHApqyACVAewCMArbAYxRABoFlVMAnInZpAS2zD3zkQoaYJAEMkAfQAm40XwGMhqDDj6pRzZqPSp6gxagC2neAEkk2Q7yj4AjHoM1OFq-IZKlaLLhvFyVGgcPRhAWNmwObmsCYABfIMd1eHQAeQAzPgBtBWDgkGZsAEcAV04CqSzUAoBzTiJEEABdBNyQsPYuHjd9Vs8auoaY90TWkGx4YsNKkFFDCM5KOSbh3uR4lZGQyiJi+CRmHRsczbyVHwJUEWYTatQN3vWek6Y2YoAbcQHu59PvNXB9jc7k8HvdHLEwUJHidjqsQPVsOlKiCRrCflUiqVytN+vVUM1IZtQqwOlFvqtRrjBvxCRTUONJtNRGBOEtGrSRtC6Xltrt9ochijuco-r4Add4LcQBzclz0Z4pNgxJw3tEaUL0V5VGLSBRqLoZUT2hFOmq0cLPB9JcVRNVzur5c8tfbLoDJcDHbKWp6QkgAF7kn2-bUXcVA6Ua7kQyMnaNBuMWhM-eIOi0YkplbAVGyZDG1PFNb104nhSJdI6GvJUwNpmgMqY5+nFEk+dkxr2VgwgXl7A41n3O-5XcOdqFFzVW6o2u39tODsXD90R+OjpMUtcjNuxyFbjxrhPR2J0ECcKAwYYA8TSWRZAT4e-3vNfMWzeaLA0o7s7XsCwggACqADKACCH4Pg+rriOWoYAKwAAwemOqZdtWL4sksejgY+X58n2YoAFKiJgogNJhWGoIqyqqngd5Ydhk7TucqCEcR8A8D4ZF0coAZisUSCUAA1AAnAAdHBCERnR+6cchfTYPm1JNi2YHkThP7-GkJhWtmMn0SRU62kxIAAGImPAnBgAAFohazuG2R6xEAA)

Format:
The Individual JSON object (with their additional attributes and may vary with other object in the array) within array can be of any 3 region: 'america', 'asia' and 'europe' and at-least on the type of region object should be there. This can be achieved by array minItems property)

Problem Statement:

1. The Individual JSON object within array can be of any 3 region: 'america', 'asia' and 'europe' and at-least on the type of region object should be there

   ==> I am able to solve this by putting all the region objects in the anyOf array as I want to match at-least one of the valid region object.
2. Either the JSON object 'asia' or 'europe' can exist along with other region type. Both cannot coexist.

   ==> I tried to use 'oneOf' but its passing the ajv validation. Actually it should fail. Can anyone help. Thanks

JSON Schema

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "stat_data": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {},
                "anyOf": [{
                        "required": ["region"],
                        "properties": {
                            "region": {
                                "enum": ["america"]
                            },
                            "country": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "population": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "oneOf": [
                            {
                                "required": ["region"],
                                "properties": {
                                    "region": {
                                        "enum": ["asia"]
                                    },
                                    "country": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "details": {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "language": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "tz": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "required": ["region"],
                                "properties": {
                                    "region": {
                                        "enum": ["europe"]
                                    },
                                    "country": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "language": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JSON Object to FAIL as both "asia" and "europe" type object cannot co-exist.

```
{
    "stat_data": [{
            "region": "america",
            "country": "USA",
            "states": "50"
        }, {
            "region": "asia",
            "country": "Japan",
            "details": {
                "language": "Japanese",
                "tz": "utc+9.00"
            }
        }, {
            "region": "europe",
            "country": "finland",
            "language": "Finnish"
        }
    ]
}
```

JSON Object to PASS as ONLY "asia" type object exist.

```
{
    "stat_data": [{
            "region": "america",
            "country": "USA",
            "states": "50"
        }, {
            "region": "asia",
            "country": "Japan",
            "details": {
                "language": "Japanese",
                "tz": "utc+9.00"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

JSON Object to PASS as ONLY "europe" type object exist.

```
{
    "stat_data": [{
            "region": "america",
            "country": "USA",
            "states": "50"
        }, {
            "region": "europe",
            "country": "finland",
            "language": "Finnish"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's helpful if as well as explaining in words what should pass and fail, you also include an example instance that should pass and fail. Sometimes words are harder than actually seeing the data =]

Comment: I have added few correct and incorrect examples in the question and my tried json schema as part of link.

Comment: Ah, this is possibly easier than I anticipated. I'll plan to post an answer today! Hint: it involves using `not`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see why you tried the approach you did, however it does not work as expected because you've defined that, each item in the array may be `america` or (`europe` or `asia`), which isn't what you want.

Remember, `items` applies the value schema to EACH element in the array. It expresses no constraints on the overall array itself. `contains` checks that at least one of the items in the array validates against its value schema.

What you want is to say, each item in the array may have `america` or `europe` or `asia`, but the array may not contain `europe` if it contains `asia`, and the inverse.

I've refactored the schema and made some changes.

Hopefully you can also see the intent is clear in the use of `oneOf` >> (`contains` and `not` > `contains`).

JSON Schema works by adding constraints. You generally cannot define constraint by omission.

[JSON Schema and data validation demo](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEASMBjAFgUwLYCGqkKI2ALhQA6QD0dAVmAPbwC0WeRAdCwE4BzOgBN+hAGYV2ABgDsdLgUIBiVABoEyVCNwSAlvH0V9bMCURwkyMpjYVChimACCYfcSiWtN7SDvwDobmXla+vqjU-CzUuPwmuCGkYeERIPy4gqbwFimpaQFgFBaohO6ePvmIAL6V4bXWvg1Nmo229o7wYACiAK7Rsbl1fgFBXUNtaVExcQlJ3pPhqBlZbBNVBWbFXqi4-TOow-VHyM3HbWfVrX4UAJ6DOyAsAEaMuJjb12TTsfH6iesbKgioQKAB9ESgzzJI6oO4PUilfjiW4aWEgfCGACSFAI8wAjF80sY8YDUnD7rgSk9Xu9PidvgNZv95nl8stMtkyRtdvBevgLABtBnkkCEfBxfSYTxEjZ+MoeNGLKq7fYPEU2AC6GquGtQdl6gX4qNCGpulOpRX4hkEh2VNl19r81BivQANqCuaanUCQPCqY8rTa7XKzqkww7ZX42LgAPISIUMtmiwhut3xxM+5DJnnoDIJx4qUR6QzGbJgOijTrONyKkBmmpR-I5lUgeAsbYwrNLPN6alF3QGIwmMyVjrBPpMkNyh0NiOpbX2x1VFu+1PpgukYXd1eitD5-vFodl0dVidqgNzpupXc99udhYznv7vuFo+lkddMeBauucrTp953yIDfEXKogLA2drAaaoQHUEB9CgGAEFgbYQXBSEHCFZMOVWHJHnFSVpSVVDSO2A0jRNREQAAVQAZRcJVRXQgFHgAVhkO0yKuBYyNI9JOTWAj-zg9EKIoY1qQAKUIahCHwpsdFwII3SSVdUA9eBBF6QhBADSBUBkuT4ESANrzICgAC9qV6ChMAAagATh4GROPrRYGm42UrD47YVi9ai9inUTFn1FhDQkqiyCHTSRCYntNO03T9NQAAxQwjDAbAuOKChPIoRdYOqIA)

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "containtsAsia": {
      "contains": {
        "properties": {
          "region": {
            "const": "asia"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "containsEurope": {
      "contains": {
        "properties": {
          "region": {
            "const": "europe"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "stat_data": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "region": {
            "enum": [
              "america",
              "asia",
              "europe"
            ]
          },
          "country": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "population": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/containtsAsia"
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/containsEurope"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/containsEurope"
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/containtsAsia"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sincere thanks for the efforts as per my requirement. Also, can't we use 'anyOf' instead of 'oneOf' as we need atleast one json object to qualify.


'oneOf' ==> One (and only one) of the contained schemas must validate against the instance value.

AnyOf : One or more of the contained schemas must validate against the instance value.

Ref: https://www.liquid-technologies.com/reference/xmlstudio/webframe.html#JsonEditorNotation_XXXOf.html

This is my view, sometimes, understanding JSON Specs are hard to interpret.

Comment: You're welcome. There's a link to my support page on my Stackoverflow profile should you wish to show more appreciation.

Comment: You could use `anyOf` in this situation, but only because the constraint is fully expressed. Often when `anyOf` is used and people encounter issues, it's because the negative opposite constraint is not expressed in the other schema(s), and it passes validation that way.

Comment: Sure. Any paypal option on kofi instead of stripe?

Comment: Yeah. Enabled it. Previously only allowed Stripe because they give better rates, but I should understand that not everyone can or wants to use that. Thanks!